# Why are jquery variables not all declared together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking at the jquery source code. It first declares a bunch of variables like this:

```
var deletedIds = [];
var slice = deletedIds.slice;
var concat = deletedIds.concat;
```

then it start declaring a comma separated list of functions and variables:

```
var
    version = "1.11.2",

    // Define a local copy of jQuery
    jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },
```

My question is why doesn't it declare all of them as a comma separated list? Or why use the comma separated list method, why not just declare all the functions and variable like the first 3?

Comment: Both methods are acceptable and correct. The answer of question can give only that person who have written this code.

Comment: jQuery is not build by writing all the code into one file by hand. They use a build system, to _concat_ all the files into the final `jquery.js` file. Those build system do some variable declaration on their own. If you want to see how jQuery is actually structured you need to look at the source on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src).